# how to check if obj is out of cam unity code 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, 2d

This was my code

```
void OnBecameInvisible()
{
    Debug.Log("he yyou lef tme");
}
```

It should debug "he yyou lef tme"

whenever the player exits the camera range but it doesn't work

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Is the method not called or is the method called but the debug message not displayed?

Comment: The debug did not show

Answer (score 0):

I personally had bad experiences using the `OnBecameVisible` function in Unity.

There are some different ways you can go about this depending on what you want to do.

using `GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB`:

```
private bool I_Can_See(GameObject Object) {

          Plane[] planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(Camera);
          if (GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes , Object.collider.bounds))
              return true;
          else
              return false;
     }
```

**Or**

Calculate the position of your player on the screen using `Camera.WorldToViewportPoint`. If this is between 0 or 1 the player is visible on the screen. More info [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToViewportPoint.html).

Like I said I prefer the methods above, because I've always had problems with the render OnBecameVisible and isVisible functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Screen Space Canvas, you can check with this script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class VisibleTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    RectTransform rect;
    Rect screenBounds = new Rect(0f, 0f, Screen.width, Screen.height);

    void Start()
    {
        rect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(IsVisible());
    }

    public bool IsVisible()
    {
        Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
        rect.GetWorldCorners(corners);

        for (var i = 0; i < corners.Length; i++)
        {
            if (screenBounds.Contains(corners[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks ideal but the world corners seem to be wrong, it thinks everything is off screen